# using ggeffect, how can I input quantitative inferences (numbers) on the effects in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot works but I can't seem to source how to input numbers on the plots for the predicted values.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, *thank you*.

code is as follows:

```
plot(ggeffect(terms=c("Age"),model=diseaseincidenceinpatients,main=""),
     facets=T,show.title = F,ci.style="errorbar",dodge=0.25)+
  ylab("Incidence of disease")+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=predicted))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Comment: Are you trying to annotate the plot?

Comment: Hi, I want to establish quantitative inferences (numbers) on the plot's effects so I can analyse them.

Comment: I am not able to understand what is being requested. "Putting numbers on the plots for predicted values" sounds like annotation. I'm guessing that you're trying to do something with that model, perhaps generating predictions from the model?

Comment: Apologies, yes I want to be able to extract the numbers for my effect plot to investigate the variables within a factor contributing to disease incidence. Any guidance?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Ggplot objects generally carry their data with them.  They also make a graphical output on the currently active device when processed with `print` or `plot`.  Perhaps if you assign that result to a name, you could look at it with `str` or `dput`